# protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, anaconda, protoc

Im attempting to install tensorflow for object detection with anaconda and python and I need to use protoc for some stuff but keep getting an error when attempting to run the command   `protoc \object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` but I keep getting the error

```
protoc The term protoc is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ protoc \object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command protoc was not found, but does exist in the current location. 
Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, 
instead type: .\protoc. See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

i have tried using the ``` '.\protoc' like anaconda suggest but still got nothing does anyone know why its doing this? i have the latestversion of anacond usinf python 3.7 and protoc 3.14

Answer (score 0):

The protobuf go pkg need to be installed, refer below link: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial